# curlでGoogle Driveにファイルをアップロードできない

Tags: php, google-api

phpのcurlを使ってGoogle Driveにファイルをアップロードするスクリプトを、[公式ドキュメント](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#uploads)を参考に作っているのですがPOSTデータの改行コードをいじくるなど何度も試したのですがcurl_execの返り値がfalseになってしまいます。どこがおかしいかご指摘頂けると助かります。

```
$token = "xxxx";
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart";

$inputarray = '';
$inputarray .= "--foo_bar_baz\r\n";
$inputarray .= "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
$inputarray .= "{\r\n";
$inputarray .= "\"name\": \"upload.jpg\",\r\n";
$inputarray .= "}\r\n\r\n";
$inputarray .= "--foo_bar_baz\r\n";
$inputarray .= "Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
$inputarray .= file_get_contents("upload.jpg") . "\r\n";
$inputarray .= "--foo_bar_baz--\r\n";


$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($inputarray)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inputarray);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

Comment: 質問の趣旨からははずれてしまいますが、curlで自分ですべて書かなければいけない、というのでなければ、[公式のphpライブラリ](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)を利用するのはどうでしょうか。やりたいことはこれだけではないでしょうから、操作をいちいち実装していくのは非常に大変になります。参考までに

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。実はやりたいことは上記のようにファイルをアップロードするだけでして、当初おっしゃるとおりphpライブラリを使うことも考えましたがサーバー側のphpバージョンを5.4に上げることによる影響などを考え、curlでの実装を試みた次第です。しかし逆に時間がかかりそうですので、改めてライブラリを使うことを検討しようと思います。

Comment: 自己解決したのであれば、質問に追記するのではなく自分で回答として投稿し、「承認」(回答の横のチェックマークを入れる)しておいてください。いつまでも未回答のまま残ってしまいます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のようにCURLOPT_POSTFIELDSの値を修正することでアップロードすることができました。

```
$token = "xxx";
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart";

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type:multipart/related",
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$token
    );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data1 = '@'.realpath('./metadata.json').';type=application/json;charset=UTF-8';
$data2 = '@'.realpath('./test.csv').';type=text/csv';

$postdata = array(
  'metadata'=>$data1,
  'file'=>$data2
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```